# Load a NSMutableArray from a file in Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I am saving a NSMutableArray to a file successfully but I can't load this Array.

Here is my loadVocab() method

```
func loadVocab() {
    let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = pathsArray[0] as String
    let vocabPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vocab")

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(vocabPath){
        self.myWords = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: vocabPath)

    }
}
```

Here is my save method

```
func saveVocab() {
    let pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = pathsArray[0] as String
    let savePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("vocab")
    self.myWords.writeToFile(savePath, atomically: true)
}
```

The Load function doesn't work, I am getting an empty Mutable Array. The Save function is working properly.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: does `writeToFile` method return true?

Comment: Can you check by printing wether self.mywords has value in it?

Comment: Does the input array to `writeToFile` only contain strings?  There's a very small number of types that this can work with

Comment: Thanks, self.mywords has a value in it. It seems that writeToFile is not working. I am investigating around the type.  I am supposed to have a MutableArray of String but I am having an Array of AnyObject

Comment: What are you store in this array? is it a `String` type or some custom classes? If so, then you have to implement `NSCoding` protocol for this class.

Comment: In the array I store data that are stored on parse.com. They are String but it seems that when I fetch the data from the backend with the API the data are AnyObject. I am trying to fix it, if I can't I will check NSCoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Parse.com cache policy to be use as a local storage between two connections to the server.

Here is the way I use my Parse query:

```
self.myData = NSMutableArray()
    var query = PFQuery(className:"entries")
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
    query.maxCacheAge = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24h maximum cache
    query.limit = self.limit
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
```

I don't need to save my Mutable Array into a file because the cache will be used. More info here https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue here you are not saving array with file extension name it is just pointing to directory.

```
let savePath = documentsDirectory
```

let filePath = savePath + "vocab.data"
Now save filePath

Same thing you should do for retrieving file data to array.